# UIButton toggling function acting weird

Tags: ios, uibutton, toggle, selected

I try to make a menu with UIButton and I just want to be able to select only one button at the time. Witch means when I select a button it's automatically deselect the other one. But it's acting weird and i don't understand why.

When I select a button from the menu it's became red and when I select a another one they are both red but I have to click 2 times on the fist button to put it black and it the same thing for the second button. The problem is when I click on the second button the first should has become black instead of stay red.

This function is called when a button is pressed with addTarget.

```
    - (void)putInSelectedMode:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"[%d] %s => %s", __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__);
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        sender = (UIButton*)sender;
        if ([sender isSelected])
        {
            [sender setSelected:NO];
            [[sender layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
            [[sender layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f];
        }
        else {

            UIButton *btn = nil;
            NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];

            for (btn in subviews) {
                if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                    [btn setSelected:NO];
                }
            }

            [[sender layer] setBorderWidth:5.0f];
            [[sender layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
            [[sender layer] setOpaque:NO];
            [sender setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an UISegmentedControl?

Comment: Also, you should clarify in what way your code is "acting weird".

Comment: Because i don't think about a UISegmentedControl it's a good suggestion...

Comment: I have the same problem seven years later.